# SwiftUI TextField re-renders the view after each character typed. How do I make it to re-render the view only after hitting the Return key?

Tags: textfield, swiftui

The same          issue exists in Xcode     beta 5    . Example code to illustrate the problem listed below
          :

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var someText = "Change me!"
    @State var someNumber = 123.0

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            // The entire View is re-rendered after each character is typed
            TextField("Text", text: $someText,
                onEditingChanged: { edit in
                    print("onEditingChanged executed!")
                },
                onCommit: {
                    print("onCommit executed!")
                }
            )

            // When you enter a Double value, the View is not re-rendered until you hit Return
            TextField("Number", value: $someNumber, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            Spacer()

            Text("text: \(self.someText), number: \(self.someNumber)")
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI `View`s will be recreated each time any of their `@ObservedObjects` change or any time their `@State` changes.

You are passing a two-way binding of the `View`'s `@State` to the `TextField`. The `TextField` updates the value of this two-way binding each time its input value changes. This will update the `@State` of the `View` and thus the `View` will be recreated.

---

I don't think you need to avoid recreating the `View` to get the effect you want. Recreating `View`s is the backbone of SwiftUI.

You can add an additional `@State` property, maybe `presentedText`, which you update to the value of `someText` inside of `onEditingChanged`.

For example (only changed for "text"):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var someText = "Change me!"
    @State var someNumber = 123.0
    @State var presentedText = someText

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            // The entire View is re-rendered after each character is typed
            TextField("Text", text: $someText,
                onEditingChanged: { edit in
                    print("onEditingChanged executed!")
                    self.presentedText = someText
                },
                onCommit: {
                    print("onCommit executed!")
                }
            )

            // When you enter a Double value, the View is not re-rendered until you hit Return
            TextField("Number", value: $someNumber, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            Spacer()

            Text("text: \(self.presentedText), number: \(self.someNumber)")
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: my animation starts again whenever i start typing. how do i stop restarting a gif image